# No internet connection alert using AFNetworking 2 and Reachability

Tags: ios, afnetworking, reachability

I'm trying to figure out how to display a "No internet connection" alert using AFNetworking 2 and Reachability.

I have Reachability and AFNetworking imported into my Controller. The part of my code that starts with `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];` I copied off of the AFNetworking 2 documentation, I'm not sure if that's where it belongs.

**UPDATE**

My app now shows an alert whenever theres no internet connection but it takes way too long for the alert to show up, I also doubt this is the best way that I can structure my code. (Also if I'm on the main view Controller and I click on a cell when there's no connection the app crashes, I dont know if there's a way to fix this).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
    {
        NSLog(@"Reachable");
    };

    reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
    {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No internet connection"
                                                         message:@"No internet connection"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
    };

    [reach startNotifier];

    self.upcomingReleases = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self makeReleasesRequests];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // Make nav items white

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[ReleaseCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReleaseCell"];
}

-(void)makeReleasesRequests
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.soleresource.com/upcoming.json"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"@");

        self.upcomingReleases = [responseObject objectForKey:@"upcoming_releases"];

        [self.collectionView reloadData];

    } failure:nil];

    [operation start];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = manager.operationQueue;
    [manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                [operationQueue setSuspended:NO];
                break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            default:
                [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
                break;
        }
    }];

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: [reach startNotifier];   is not optional it's requires to start notifying.

Comment: [Check this for what if connection lost during process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009120/reachability-notification-and-tableviewcontroller/20009749#20009749)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with reachability

```
Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
{
  UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Reachable" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

  [alrt performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:yes];  
};

reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
{
  UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Not Reachable" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

  [alrt performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:yes];  
 };


[reach startNotifier];
```

Comment: I updated my app with your code as a starting point, it now shows an alert whenever theres no internet connection but it takes way too long for the alert to show up. I also doubt thats the best way that I can structure my code.

Comment: Did you calculate that time.... it's not too much, I always use this and I never get problem with this.

Comment: Perform what-ever you want in reachableBlock with main thread and it works fine

Comment: The app opens it shows a blank page (since it can't load any cells), then maybe 8 seconds later the alert shows up. I also dont know what you mean with "perform whatever you want in reachableblock..."

Comment: Did you show alert view in main thread like             [yourAlrt performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:yes];

Answer (score 5):

I use the **AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification**. Every time a http request will fail, the alert pops up and informs the user.

```
- (void)addNetworkObserver
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(HTTPOperationDidFinish:) 
                                                name:AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification 
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)HTTPOperationDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
   AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)[notification object];
   if (![operation isKindOfClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]]) {
       return;
   }
   if (operation.error) {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection error"
                                                       message:@"Missing connection to the internet"
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

       [alert show];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ahh I was having the same exact issue, you need to remove [alert show] and add to main thread, so it should look like this,

```
 UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No internet connection"
                                                         message:@"No internet connection"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
       // [alert show];
        NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
        [alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AFNetworking 3.0, call this code on ViewDidLoad or your AppDelegate :

```
// Monitoring Reachability
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));

    // Add your alert here
}];

[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calling startMonitoring on the reachabilityManager (stick with the one built in to AFNetworking 2, adding in Reachability is redundant in this case).

```
[manager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring]
```

You can test this out by toggling on/off airplane mode on your device or simulator. Keep in mind, this won't handle cases with timeouts/slow connections/bad requests. That's something you'll have to handle along with this.